# How to create and save CSV files in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, csv, react-native

My React Native app (on android only) is a basic app that will collect some sensors data when users start recording video. I have three arrays of sensors data: accelerometer, gyroscope, and light. I want to save them to the device as `.csv` files so I can use them for the next steps. Currently, I can save them in `.txt` (using react-native-fs, but they do not support `.csv` extension) but what I want is `.csv`. Is there any way to do that in React Native?

Data will look like this:

```
this.accelerometer = [
  {x: 12, y: 15, z: 17},
  {x: 12, y: 15, z: 17},
  ...
  {x: 12, y: 15, z: 17},
]

this.gyroscope = [
  {x: 12, y: 15, z: 17},
  {x: 12, y: 15, z: 17},
  ...
  {x: 12, y: 15, z: 17},
]

this.light = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10,.., 11]
```

Desired `.csv`, for example `accelerometer.csv`:

```
x ,y ,z
12,15,17
```

Comment: Have a look at fs. You can create a string and save it as csv. Afterall, csv is just a string with commas and newlines right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) to write to the device's file system. (I was wondering this too!)

We start by converting an array of values to a string. If our values are separated by `,` commas and our rows are separated by `\n` newlines, then our string is **csv**.  We can take that string, write it to a file with a `.csv` file extension, and *voila* we have a `.csv` file.

here's code that does just this:

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

const values = [
  ['build', '2017-11-05T05:40:35.515Z'],
  ['deploy', '2017-11-05T05:42:04.810Z']
];

// construct csvString
const headerString = 'event,timestamp\n';
const rowString = values.map(d => `${d[0]},${d[1]}\n`).join('');
const csvString = `${headerString}${rowString}`;

// write the current list of answers to a local csv file
const pathToWrite = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/data.csv`;
console.log('pathToWrite', pathToWrite);
// pathToWrite /storage/emulated/0/Download/data.csv
RNFetchBlob.fs
  .writeFile(pathToWrite, csvString, 'utf8')
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`wrote file ${pathToWrite}`);
    // wrote file /storage/emulated/0/Download/data.csv
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

this approach worked for me on an Android 7.x test device.

in case it's helpful, I'll also share a [link to the equivalent code](https://github.com/micahstubbs/curious-app/blob/master/app/index.js#L138) inside my react-native project

Comment: note that there are many packages for csv encoding, if you want to do fancy things and handle strange edge cases. this time, this simple approach worked for me.  https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=encode+csv

Comment: Probably a little off-topic but is there a way to let the user know that the file got downloaded/created? Kind of like "Downloaded" notification. I do see that we can use `.config` for `.fetch` but doesn't seem to appear for `.fs`. My solution right now has been to use extra notification package and notify on `.then` but that seems a little un-necessary given how `react-native-fetch-blob` should have this already.

Comment: This was a great help, but if you're on iOS, remember to use `DocumentDir` instead of `DownloadDir` (which is Android only). Also, the project has been forked and renamed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob

Comment: This is a great way to construct the csv data.
You can also use `react-native-fs` to write the file.

Comment: Any solution for Expo project?

Answer (score 1):

Some other way

```
    createFile = () => {
    csvString = `${HEADER}`;
    RNFetchBlob.fs
        .writeFile(FILE_PATH, csvString, "utf8")
        .then(() => {
            alert("File created succesfully");
            this.saveData(JSON.stringify([]));
            this.setState({
                users: []
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
};

writeCSV = () => {
    try {

        let rowData = [{
            Name: "ABC",
            MobileNo: 9999999999,
            Age: 23
        }, {
            Name: "DEF",
            MobileNo: 9999999998,
            Age: 24
        }]


        const csvString = `${HEADER}${this.ConvertToCSV(rowData)}`;
        RNFetchBlob.fs
            .writeFile(FILE_PATH, csvString, "utf8")
            .then(() => {
                alert("File updated succesfully");

            })
            .catch(error => alert(error));

    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
    }
};


ConvertToCSV = objArray => {
    var array = typeof objArray != "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = "";
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != "") line += ",";

            line += array[i][index];
        }

        str += line + "\r\n";
    }

    return str;
};
```